# iOS Keychain access and Provisioning Profiles

Tags: ios, keychain, provisioning-profile, codesign

Just came across this on apple [Keychain Services Concepts](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000897-CH208-SW1)

> Note: On iPhone, Keychain rights depend on the provisioning profile
> used to sign your application. Be sure to consistently use the same
> provisioning profile across different versions of your application.

I also know that provisioning profiles can change for many reasons, including adding a new functionality like push notification, adding watch support, or even adding a new team member.

Now am I correct to assume that whenever above changes occur, new versions of my app will no longer be able to access keychain items that were created with previous versions?

Thanks!

Comment: You can still access it!

Comment: Latest Apple doc removed the description of '...Keychain rights depend on the provisioning profile...', maybe they found it can confuse people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your assumption is right. The **Keychain Acces** only depends on the *bundle identifier* of your application and the profile which was first used to create the app. If it would depend of your **code-provisioning profiles changes**, indeed what you said would be correct, but if so, the bussinesses and the enterprises would be totally unable to develop updates for their applications, which would have also included the old info stored in the Keychain. That's because in a bussiness, people come and leave often!

> Note: On iPhone, Keychain rights depend on the provisioning profile used to sign your application. Be sure to consistently use the same provisioning profile across different versions of your application.

You can add a team member, configure a push notification services and so on, as long as the provisioning profile stays the same.

**Note:** If you change the provisioning profile just to add a team member, yes, your assumption is right, but it just isn't the best way of doing this. Rather, I recommend reading [this tutorial (on how to add a team member to a provisioning profile)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ManagingYourTeam/ManagingYourTeam.html).

Comment: let me know if it helped you understand Keychain Better!

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder I'm not sure I follow your response: you mention "If you change the provisioning profile just to add a team member, yes, your assumption is right", but there are other reasons to generate a new provisioning profile, such as when you need to refresh your app store provisioning profile after your app store certificate expires. Would this cause your keychain items to invalidate, and if not, why not?

Comment: @AlexanderWallaceMatchneer My Xcode development knowledge is a bit rusty (it's been more than a year since I last used it), so I am not sure if my knowledge is 100% accurate. But as far as I know, access to the keychain is only based off the bundle identifier of your application, so I don't think that changing the provisioning profiles _should_ matter. But as I said, I am not certain.

Answer (score 1):

keychain directly depepds on Bundle id , if bundle id remain same then your app can acess keychain , so provisioning profile should map the same bundle id if app needs to acccess keychain.